# Movie about space, aliens that are humans, sleeper agents

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing a movie (or seeing parts of it) many many years ago (like 10 - 12 years) that I only remember brief scenes from it.

In the movie there was something to do with some TV ad that played that triggered a young girl who was with the protagonists (unsure of why) to go on some killing rampage, and it turned out the TV ad had some hidden message inside it that activated her as a sleeper agent.

I think the people in the movie were able to trace down the hidden message to its origin from an unidentified planet in the middle of the aliens zone.

If I remember correctly, the setting was something like humans are now on another planet fighting barbaric aliens (who make their ships very mad max style I think? Can't exactly remember) but it turns out that these barbaric aliens are the remaining humans who escaped earth after something (I think some corporation... unsure) decided to euthanise everyone on earth.

I recall a scene of the main characters going to earth and walking through the streets passed a diner and a woman (or man... a human) had her face pressed up against the glass and her face was preserved but the rest of her had decomposed (don't remember much more).

Does anyone know what this movie is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [**Serenity**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/) (2005) the movie follow up to the *Firefly* TV series.

> The siblings have found refuge aboard the transport spaceship Serenity with Captain Malcolm "Mal" Reynolds (Nathan Fillion), first mate Zoe Washburne (Gina Torres), pilot Hoban "Wash" Washburne (Alan Tudyk), mercenary Jayne Cobb (Adam Baldwin), and mechanic Kaylee Frye (Jewel Staite). Despite Simon's objections, Mal brings River on a bank robbery. River warns them that savage and **cannibalistic Reavers are coming.** They escape, but Simon decides he and River will leave Serenity at the next port. Once there, however, **a subliminal message in a television commercial causes River to attack numerous bar patrons**, and Mal takes the siblings back aboard the ship. The crew contacts reclusive hacker Mr. Universe (David Krumholtz), who discovers the message. It is designed to trigger River's mental conditioning. He notes **River whispered "Miranda" before attacking and warns that someone else saw the footage**.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_(film))

---

> I recall a scene of the main characters going to earth and walking through the streets passed a diner and a woman (or man... a human) had her face pressed up against the glass and her face was preserved but the rest of her had decomposed (don't remember much more).

[image]

---

> If I remember correctly, the setting was something like humans are now on another planet fighting barbaric aliens (who make their ships very mad max style I think? Can't exactly remember) but it turns out that these barbaric aliens are the remaining humans who escaped earth after something (I think some corporation... unsure) decided to euthanise everyone on earth.

From a [Wikia](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Reaver)

> Reavers originated from Miranda, the outermost planet in a distant solar system. The Alliance had been testing behavioral modification on this planet through the chemical G-23 Paxilon Hydrochlorate (a.k.a. "The Pax" (Latin for "Peace")), administered through the air recycling systems. **The chemical was designed to weed out aggression and anger.** The ultimate result was that 99.9% of the population stopped going to work, talking to each other, and eventually stopped moving, eating or breeding, and therefore died. However, the remaining 0.1% ("a tenth of one percent") of the population had the opposite reaction, with their aggression and primal instincts boosted beyond simple madness into murderous rage, sadism and savagery.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was point for point the movie I was looking for